# Chrome extension to run jquery and add my own css

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I would like to ask you how to make my own chrome extension by making a chrome extension run (when i click the button), after the load of the page
and make my own css in the page and also run my own jquery code.

the html code of the page that i want to edit is the following.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="groupHeader">Semester A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" class="italicHeader">
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">Course</td>
                    <td valign="top">Type</td>
                    <td valign="top">SM</td>
                    <td valign="top">Hours</td>
                    <td valign="top">ECTS</td>
                    <td valign="top">Grade</td>
                    <td valign="top">Exam</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="25" bgcolor="#fafafa">
                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;<img align="absbottom" src="images/course4.gif" width="16"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="topBorderLight">(Ν2-1011)&nbsp; PHYSICS<span class="redfonts"></span></td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">COMPULSORY</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 6</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight">6</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"> 7</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="topBorderLight"><span class="redFonts">5,5</span></td>
                    <td nowrap="true" class="topBorderLight"><span class="tablecell"><i>Α WINTER&nbsp;
                        2012-2013</i></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So i will add this css code

```
.gradeOver5,
.gradeOver5 td {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

and run this jquery code when the page is loaded.

```
(function ( $ ) {

$('.topBorderLight').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var grade = Number($this.text());
    if(!isNaN(grade)) {
        $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade > 5);
    }
});

}( jQuery ));
```

What should my manifest be like so these codes can work together?

I believe it should be something like this but correct me if im wrong

```
    {
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "img/icon19.png",
      "default_title": "test"
   },
   "content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches":["<all_urls>"],
            "js":["thirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "content_script.js"],
            "css": ["css/mystyle.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],

   "icons": {
      "128": "img/icon128.png",
      "19": "img/icon19.png",
      "38": "img/icon38.png",
      "48": "img/icon48.png"
   },
   "name": "test",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": " test",
   "permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
   "version": "1"
}
```

The css/mystyle.css contains the css that i have written above.
Also the content_script contains the jquery code from above.

Then background.js something like this

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    allFrames: true,
        file: "content_script.js"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });


});
```

With the above extension im trying to make with the click to add a crossing red line to every part of the row in the table, as you can see in this link

http://jsfiddle.net/btatr2wn/1/

But when i try it its not working. could someone help me find the error?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i made it work i forgot to put the function in the content script

```
(function ( $ ) {

$('.topBorderLight').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var grade = Number($this.text());
    if(!isNaN(grade)) {
        $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('gradeOver5', grade > 5);
    }
});

}( jQuery ));
```